Problema con la detección y procesamiento automático de archivos en MinIO con Airflow DAGs
Estoy intentando detectar automáticamente archivos en un bucket S3 y limpiarlos con Airflow DAGs, pero no consigo detectarlos:
El fichero está en el bucket shared-results de mi instancia de minio, en la ruta: la-empressa-e2e/new-data/: la-empressa-e2e/new-data/velocidad_0.csv.
Para detectar nuevos ficheros hago:
import time
from airflow.sensors.base import BaseSensorOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
import boto3

class MinioKeySensor(BaseSensorOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, bucket_name, prefix, aws_conn_id='aws_default', *args, **kwargs):
        super(MinioKeySensor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bucket_name = bucket_name
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.aws_conn_id = aws_conn_id

    def poke(self, context):
        s3_client = boto3.client(
            's3',
            endpoint_url='https://minio-storage.laempressa.com',
            aws_access_key_id='secret_key_id_jajaja',
            aws_secret_access_key='secret_access_key_jajaja'
        )
        response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Prefix=self.prefix)
        print("response: ", response)
        if 'Contents' in response:
            return True
        return False

Que llamo desde:
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np
import subprocess
import sys

# Configuration MinIO
MINIO_ACCESS_KEY = 'access_key_jajaja'
MINIO_SECRET_KEY = 'secret_jajaja'
MINIO_URL = 'https://minio-storage.laempresa.com'
BUCKET_NAME = 'shared-results'
PREFIX = 'la_empressa/new-data'

def install_scipy():
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "scipy"])

def process_vibration_data(**kwargs):
    from ec1_fa38.data_transformer import transform_data
    
    file_key = kwargs['file_key']
    print(f"Processing file: {file_key}")

    # Fonction pour télécharger les données depuis Minio
    def download_data_from_minio(file_key):
        s3_client = boto3.client(
            's3',
            endpoint_url=MINIO_URL,
            aws_access_key_id=MINIO_ACCESS_KEY,
            aws_secret_access_key=MINIO_SECRET_KEY
        )
        obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=file_key)
        return obj['Body'].read()

    # Fonction de vérification de la conformité des données
    def check_data_compliance(data):
        df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data))
        if df.isnull().values.any():
            raise ValueError("Les données contiennent des valeurs nulles.")
        return df

    # Fonction de calcul des métriques
    def calculate_metrics(df, file_key):
        metrics = {
            'mean': df.mean()[0],
            'std_dev': df.std()[0],
            'max': df.max()[0],
            'min': df.min()[0]
        }

        metrics_df = pd.DataFrame([metrics])
        
        metrics_file = io.StringIO()
        metrics_df.to_csv(metrics_file, index=False)
        
        s3_client = boto3.client(
            's3',
            endpoint_url=MINIO_URL,
            aws_access_key_id=MINIO_ACCESS_KEY,
            aws_secret_access_key=MINIO_SECRET_KEY
        )
        s3_client.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=f'metrics/{file_key}.csv', Body=metrics_file.getvalue())
        
        print("Metrics saved: ", metrics)
        return metrics

    data = download_data_from_minio(file_key)
    df = check_data_compliance(data)
    df = transform_data(df, fs, nbPtsFFT, spctrOverlapPrct, IMGLENGTH, max_frequency)
    calculate_metrics(df, file_key)

# Import the custom MinioKeySensor
from ec1_fa38.sensors import MinioKeySensor

# constantes de preprocessing
acquisition_campaigns_train = ["1", "2"]
acquisition_campaigns_test = ["3"]
rotation_frequencies = ["30Hz"]
fs = 25600
nbPtsFFT = 1024
spctrOverlapPrct = 90.
apodization = 'hann'
IMGLENGTH = 0.2
MINIMGSHIFT = 0.1
max_frequency = 800
subsampling_factor = 16

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'retries': 1,
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='UC_LAEMPRESSA_new_data',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Un pipeline pour les données de vibrations',
    schedule_interval='@daily',
)

sense_new_file = MinioKeySensor(
    task_id='sense_new_file',
    bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME,
    prefix=PREFIX,
    poke_interval=120,
    timeout=18*60*60,
    dag=dag,
)

install_scipy_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='install_scipy',
    python_callable=install_scipy,
    dag=dag,
)

process_data_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='process_vibration_data',
    python_callable=process_vibration_data,
    op_kwargs={'file_key': '{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids="sense_new_file") }}'},
    dag=dag,
)

sense_new_file >> install_scipy_task >> process_data_task

Pero me devuelve:
airflow-worker-0.airflow-worker.confiance.svc.cluster.local
*** Found logs served from host http://airflow-worker-0.airflow-worker.confiance.svc.cluster.local:8793/log/dag_id=UC_LAEMPRESSA_new_data/run_id=manual__2024-07-25T12:58:28.060160+00:00/task_id=process_vibration_data/attempt=2.log
[2024-07-25, 13:03:44 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1979} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=non-requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: UC_LAEMPRESSA_new_data.process_vibration_data manual__2024-07-25T12:58:28.060160+00:00 [queued]>
[2024-07-25, 13:03:44 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1979} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: UC_LAEMPRESSA_new_data.process_vibration_data manual__2024-07-25T12:58:28.060160+00:00 [queued]>
[2024-07-25, 13:03:44 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2193} INFO - Starting attempt 2 of 2
[2024-07-25, 13:03:44 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2217} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): process_vibration_data> on 2024-07-25 12:58:28.060160+00:00
[2024-07-25, 13:03:44 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:60} INFO - Started process 1118845 to run task
[2024-07-25, 13:03:44 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:87} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'UC_LAEMPRESSA_new_data', 'process_vibration_data', 'manual__2024-07-25T12:58:28.060160+00:00', '--job-id', '3597', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/UC_LAEMPRESSA_new_data.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpkdpca2qx']
[2024-07-25, 13:03:44 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:88} INFO - Job 3597: Subtask process_vibration_data
[2024-07-25, 13:03:44 UTC] {task_command.py:423} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: UC_LAEMPRESSA_new_data.process_vibration_data manual__2024-07-25T12:58:28.060160+00:00 [running]> on host airflow-worker-0.airflow-worker.confiance.svc.cluster.local
[2024-07-25, 13:03:44 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2513} INFO - Exporting env vars: AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER='airflow' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID='UC_LAEMPRESSA_new_data' AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID='process_vibration_data' AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE='2024-07-25T12:58:28.060160+00:00' AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER='2' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID='manual__2024-07-25T12:58:28.060160+00:00'
[2024-07-25, 13:03:45 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:188} INFO - Processing file: None
[2024-07-25, 13:03:45 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2731} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 444, in _execute_task
    result = _execute_callable(context=context, **execute_callable_kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 414, in _execute_callable
    return execute_callable(context=context, **execute_callable_kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 200, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 217, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/repo/UC_LAEMPRESSA_new_data.py", line 70, in process_vibration_data
    data = download_data_from_minio(file_key)
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/repo/UC_LAEMPRESSA_new_data.py", line 35, in download_data_from_minio
    obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=file_key)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 553, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1009, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
[2024-07-25, 13:03:45 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1149} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=UC_LAEMPRESSA_new_data, task_id=process_vibration_data, execution_date=20240725T125828, start_date=20240725T130344, end_date=20240725T130345
[2024-07-25, 13:03:45 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:107} ERROR - Failed to execute job 3597 for task process_vibration_data (An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.; 1118845)
[2024-07-25, 13:03:45 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:234} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2024-07-25, 13:03:45 UTC] {taskinstance.py:3312} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check

